# How to merge the duplicate code in one method because there are 4 imageView would be used in same code

Tags: java, android

Here create a function to paint the line in each imageView. There are 4 imageView will use the duplicate code

```
public class ChildrenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4;
        Canvas canvas1, canvas2;
        Paint paint;
        Bitmap baseBitmap1, baseBitmap2, baseBitmap3, baseBitmap4;
    
        float startX,startY;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_children);
    
            imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
```

Here attached the ImageView1 to implement the painting function.  Please advice me to solve the problem.

```
            imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    
                        if (baseBitmap1 == null) {
                            baseBitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView1.getWidth(), imageView1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            canvas1 = new Canvas(baseBitmap1);
                            canvas1.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        break;
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        float endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        canvas1.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
    
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        imageView1.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap1);
                        break;
                }
    
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Here attached the ImageView2 to implement the painting function. Please advice me to solve the problem.

```
        imageView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    
                        if (baseBitmap2 == null) {
                            baseBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView2.getWidth(), imageView2.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            canvas2 = new Canvas(baseBitmap2);
                            canvas2.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        break;
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        float endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        canvas2.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
    
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        imageView2.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap2);
                        break;
                }
    
                return true;
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

[Here got the error message according to Steve comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeDn6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to extract the listener setups to a method of it's own.

Like this:

```
public void RegisterImageViewTouchListener(final ImageView imageView, final Bitmap bitmap, final Canvas canvas)
{
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    
                        if (bitmap== null) {
                            bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            canvas= new Canvas(baseBitmap1);
                            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        break;
    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float endX = motionEvent.getX();
                        float endY = motionEvent.getY();
                        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
    
                        startX = motionEvent.getX();
                        startY = motionEvent.getY();
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        break;
                }
    
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

And then invoke the method, like this:

```
RegisterImageViewTouchListener(imageView1, baseBitmap1, canvas1);
RegisterImageViewTouchListener(imageView2, baseBitmap2, canvas2);
```

You could take this one step further and store your ImageView, Bitmap and Canvas objects in an ArrayList and then loop over them whilst calling the method above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got the error message "Variable 'bitmap' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final" and "Variable 'canvas' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final". Please advise.

Comment: The answer is to make your Bitmap variable final by declaring it as so. For example, final Bitmap baseBitmap1. I assume the final keyword is fine for you to use here. More information regarding the final keyword can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Essentially, instead of declaring them as final, just declare the parameters within the method signature as final.

Comment: I revised "final Bitmap bitmap, final Canvas canvas" but I got "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'bitmap"